# How can one reset an HTMLAudioElement's current playback position to 0?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-video, html5-audio

Check out this demo page: http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play10.htm

Click the `Play Sound` button twice, in quick succession.  Because it hasn't yet finished playing the first time around by the time you hit the button again, nothing happens, and the click appears to be ignored.  How could one re-code it so that it would stop the current playback, reset the playback position to the very beginning of the sound, and restart it upon each click of the `Play Sound` button?

Comment: NOTE: I only ask because it seems the docs are broken: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/NsIDOMHTMLMediaElement

Comment: Implement your own play controls? "Seeking through media" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the it to something like this

```
var thissound=document.getElementById('audioElemID');
thissound.currentTime=0;
thissound.play();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.. Am I doing something wrong? (grep for #FIXME) http://jsbin.com/izoleg/1/edit

Comment: Well actually, it works when I modify the `EvalSound` function in the console on the linked page.  But it isn't working for whatever reason on my bin... any clue why?

Answer (score 2):

```
thissound=document.getElementById(soundobj);
thissound.currentTime = 0;
```